# Getting rid of Netbeans NavData files

Tags: jsf, configuration, netbeans

I'm using netbeans and maven in my project and for JSF configuration files it generates some .NavData files.

This bothers me during backing up my project and also is inconvenient for versioning systems.

How can i configure to use another folder for these files, e.g. target would be awesome.

Any ideas?

Thx.

Answer (score -1):

These files are generated by plugins or specific editors of the IDE (NetBeans or Eclipse for example). They starts with a `.` in order to be hidden in Linux file systems.

I am pretty sure that you cannot change the directory where they are located, so the best solution is to add them in the `.cvsignore` or `.svnignore` or `.gitignore` file (depending on which Version Control System you are using). So these files will ignored during the VCS synchronization.

Comment: .NavData is the file extension not the name itself and also i'm ignoring these files for the used versioning system. Any other suggestions? thx.